# regular expression pattern matching objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, regex, nsregularexpression

I have the following string:

```
"abbot n. The superior of a community of monks."
```

how would I separate

```
"abbot"
```

and

```
"n. The superior of a community of monks."
```

effectively?

The logic I would like to use would be something like searching the large string to the first space then splitting the word based on that.

I am writing this in objective-c.

Are there any abstractions that can make it easier for me?

Comment: I have: /[^ ]*/ as the regex to use to match up to the first encounter with the character in the string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using this pattern will give two groups containing the matches you needed:

```
"(.+?)\s+(\w\.\s+.+?)"
```

Comment: got it to work. it almost works! but it does not return the full second group   --------                    group1: abbot
group2: n. T

Comment: solved the problem by subtracting the first word from the large word. thanks!!